# How to extract specific column from 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array and i want to extract specific column from it, let's say the 3rd column only.

**Example:**

> 1  2  3  4
>   1  2  3  4
>   1  2  3  4
>   1  2  3  4

What is want is to extract 3rd column and display only:

> 3
>   3
>   3
>   3

This is my code where i am able to create a dynamic array specified by the user:

```
int r;
int c;
Console.Write("Enter number of rows: ");
r = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter number of columns: ");
c = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] matrix = new int[r, c];

/*Insert Values into Main Matrix
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter value for matrix[{0},{1}] = ",row, col);
        matrix[row, col] = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}


/*Print and show initial Matrix
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
Console.WriteLine("Your matrix is,");
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < c; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


/*Fixing first 2 columns
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int startingMatrixCols = 2;
Console.WriteLine("Fixed first 2 columns:");
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < startingMatrixCols; col++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: `if (col == 2) { Console.Write(matrix[row, col] + " "); }` ?

Comment: Or simply `Console.WriteLine(matrix[row, 2]);`...

Comment: Leave your original question after the answer has been found so other users can see what the question was and benefit from the answers

Comment: As it stands, this question should be deleted, or the edit rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var column = 2; // your expected column
    //if it needs to be dynamic, you can read it from user entry
    // Console.Write("Enter expected column: ");
    // column = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //enhance with error checks
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: I tried it when i ask for column 2 the output is linear like this : 2 2 2 2 but i want them each under the other like in a matrix

Comment: i added Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " " + "\n");   \n to break at each so i can get them each under the other thank you

Comment: Just use WriteLine(matrix[row, column]) instead of Write

Answer (score -2):

```
Console.Write("Enter the column number to display ");
int displayColNo = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

/*If displayColNo=3 it displays only 3rd column numbers*/
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++)
{
    Console.Write(matrix[row, displayColNo]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```